# dynamic cdi with @Any

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

In our Java EE application, we process different file types. But instead of injecting all types as

```
@Any
@Inject
private Instance<FileHandler> handler
```

We do it with a big switch. All handler to extend from FileHandler, it's a abstract class, not an interface. Is there a way to make it generic? From what I can see with Instance, you still have to pass the class file of the implementation you wanna use.

```
@Inject
private XmlHandler xmlHandler;

@Inject
private CsvHandler csvHandler;


public void method(String fileType) {
    switch (fileType) {
        case "xml":
            xmlHandler.handle();
            break;
        case "csv":
            csvHandler.handle();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum to list all of them:

```
public enum FileHandlers {
    XmlHandler,
    CsvHandler
}
```

Qualifier to specify:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier 
public @interface FileHandlerChooser {
FileHandlers choose();
}
```

Implementation:

```
@FileHandlerChooser(choose = FileHandlers.XmlHandler)
public class XmlHandler implements FileHandler {

...

}
```

Injection:

```
@Inject
@FileHandlerChooser(choose = FileHandlers.XmlHandler)
private FileHandler fileHandler;
```

Comment: But then I still have my switch case? And all the different handlers injected separately.